# finding number in string REGEX

Tags: python, regex

I am very new to regex and learning by practice. I wrote the following regex for finding a number inside a string of characters, however, it returns nothing. Why is that?

```
string = "hello world & bello stack 12456";

findObj = re.match(r'[0-9]+',string,re.I);

if findObj:
    print findObj.group();
else:
    print "nothing matched"
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.match` must match from the beginning of the string.
Use `re.search` instead.

Comment: And how can I find the length of groups? Does each substring is returned by group(i)?

Comment: `re.search` only finds the first match (if any). If you want all matches, use [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Comment: thanks alot. If you can refer me to an easy to learn python documentation/tutorial just like Android documentation, that would be great.

Comment: I don't know what the Android docs are like, but for Python I would start by reading the [Python3 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or [Python2 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/), depending on the version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 3):

`re.match` matches from the start of the string. Use `re.search`

```
>>> my_string = "hello world & bello stack 12456"
>>> find_obj = re.search(r'[0-9]+', my_string, re.I)
>>> print find_obj.group()
12456
```

P.S semicolons are not necessary.